# ipa replica install cmd failed certutil -d /etc/httpd/alias -A -n ServerCert -t , -a -f /etc/httpd/alias/pwdfile.txt retuned non-zero exit status 255

Tags: freeipa

```
Master server: aaa01
Replica server1:  dir01 (currently installing replica server )
Replica server2: dirus02 (which was a replica server previously that has been removed from replication)
```

> As noticed while installing ipa replica server, replica server retrieving two certificates from the master server, and saving it in /etc/ipa/ca.crt in this process at the stage Configuring the web interface (httpd)  we got the below error i.e.

```
ipa-replica-install command failed, exception: CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/bin/certutil -d dbm:/etc/httpd/alias -A -n Server-Cert -t ,, -a -f /etc/httpd/alias/pwdfile.txt' returned non-zero exit status 255

===============================================
```

`While installing Replica /var/log/ipaclient-install.log`
---------------------------------------------------

````
2022-08-15T13:52:08Z DEBUG stderr=
2022-08-15T13:52:08Z DEBUG trying to retrieve CA cert via LDAP from aaa01.ipa.subdomain.com
2022-08-15T13:52:09Z DEBUG retrieving schema for SchemaCache url=ldap://aaa01.ipa.subdomain.com:389 conn=<ldap.ldapobject.SimpleLDAPObject instance at 0x7f17fe812440>
2022-08-15T13:52:11Z INFO Successfully retrieved CA cert

Subject:     CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
Issuer:      CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
Valid From:  2018-04-12 14:15:30
Valid Until: 2038-04-12 14:15:30

Subject:     CN=dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
Issuer:      CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
Valid From:  2019-01-21 11:54:13
Valid Until: 2021-01-21 11:54:13

2022-08-15T13:52:11Z DEBUG Starting external process
2022-08-15T13:52:11Z DEBUG args=/usr/sbin/ipa-join -s aaa01.ipa.subdomain.com -b dc=ipa,dc=example,dc=com -h dirpav01-tfln-mdr1-omes.ipa.subdomain.com
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG stdout=
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG stderr=Keytab successfully retrieved and stored in: /etc/krb5.keytab
Certificate subject base is: O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM

2022-08-15T13:52:15Z INFO Enrolled in IPA realm IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG Starting external process
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG args=/usr/bin/kdestroy
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2022-08-15T13:52:15Z DEBUG stdout=

==================================



```While installing replica  /var/log/ipareplica-install.log```
--------------------------------------------------

2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG   [14/22]: importing CA certificates from LDAP
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG Loading Index file from '/var/lib/ipa/sysrestore/sysrestore.index'
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG Starting external process
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG args=/usr/bin/certutil -d dbm:/etc/httpd/alias -A -n IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM IPA CA -t CT,C,C -a -f /etc/httpd/alias/pwdfile.txt
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG stdout=
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG stderr=
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG Starting external process
2022-08-15T15:07:11Z DEBUG args=/usr/bin/certutil -d dbm:/etc/httpd/alias -A -n Server-Cert -t ,, -a -f /etc/httpd/alias/pwdfile.txt
2022-08-15T15:07:12Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=255
2022-08-15T15:07:12Z DEBUG stdout=
2022-08-15T15:07:12Z DEBUG stderr=certutil: could not add certificate to token or database: SEC_ERROR_ADDING_CERT: Error adding certificate to database.

2022-08-15T15:07:12Z DEBUG Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 567, in start_creation
    run_step(full_msg, method)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/service.py", line 557, in run_step
````

> Observation in Master server(aaa01)  ldap database : ```
> =======================================

```
[root@aaa01~]# ldapsearch -D 'cn=directory manager' -w XXXXXXXXX | grep    "ipaCertSubject"
ipaCertSubject: CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
ipaCertSubject: CN=dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
[root@aaa01~]#

====================
We could see this certificate "CN=dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM" in IPA master server GUI as well we have revoked it too , but still it retrieves the same and  installation got fails everytime

=================

In ideal case while installing replica it has to retrieve only one certificate i.e. CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM but this case it  retrieves 


Please let us know if any more details required and let us know how can we fix this issue, without impact on whole setup  

ipaCertIssuerSerial from ldap search command on IPA master 

ipaCertIssuerSerial: CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM;1   [which is a valid certificate]
ipaCertIssuerSerial: CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM;32  [ invalid certificate retrieves from ipa master while installing ipa replica]
```

> [root@aaa01]# ipa cert-show

```
Serial number: 32
  Issuing CA: ipa
  Certificate: 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
  Subject: CN=dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
  Subject DNS name: dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com
  Subject UPN: HTTP/dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com@IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
  Subject Kerberos principal name: HTTP/dirus02.ipa.subdomain.com@IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
  Issuer: CN=Certificate Authority,O=IPA.SUBDOMAIN.COM
  Not Before: Mon Jan 21 11:54:13 2019 UTC
  Not After: Thu Jan 21 11:54:13 2021 UTC
  Serial number: 32
  Serial number (hex): 0x20
  Revoked: True
  Revocation reason: 2
[root@aaa01~]#
```

> 